# If statement based on Countdown Timer on ReactJS not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, countdowntimer

I have a JS countdown timer that works great and displays great into my home page. Now, I'm trying to implement an IF statement in my rendered DIV to display a button for OPEN when Timer is at 0 or APP CLOSED if timer is still going. This is what I have on my React Home Page, and this is my Countdown.js Page:

This is the if statement: {distance < 0 ? OPEN : APP CLOSED}

**Home Page**

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../App.css';
import Countdown from '../Countdown';



const distance = Countdown ();


function Home() {






  return (
    <>
    <div className="App">
        <div>
          <div className='hero-container'>
          <div class="courses-container">
    <div class="course">
        <div class="course-preview">
            <h6>Welcome</h6>
            <h2>PROJECT NAME</h2>
      
        </div>
        <div class="course-info">
            <div class="progress-container">
                <span class="progress-text">
                    /1000
                </span>
            </div>
            <h2 id="demo"></h2>
      <div id='input-number' className='input-number-location'>
    <input className='input-number button' type="number" name="amount" defaultValue="1" min="1" max="20"/>
  </div>
            {distance < 0 ? <button class="btncard">OPEN</button> : <button class="btncard">APP CLOSED</button>}
        </div>
    {/*NEED TO FIX THIS IF STATEMENT /\ */}
    </div>
</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

**Countdown Timer**

```
function Countdown () {

    
    // Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jun 27, 2022 22:27:10").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Mint is Live!";
  
  }
}, 1000);

}

export default Countdown;
```

Comment: I think the problem here is that your countdown function isn't returning any value, so when you're using the distance var it is just calling the countdown function. you can check it by console logging the distance.

Comment: In the home page file, `distance` is a `Counter`, not a number. You need to have `Counter` have [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) that you can read from outside the component.

Comment: That worked great! Thanks! I created a useState for the Countdown Function and passed down with a useEffect based on my timers and distance.